# Prove that $(a-x)^6-3a(a-x)^5+\frac{5}{2} a^2(a-x)^4-\frac{1}{2} a^4 (a-x)^2 <0$ for $0<x<a,$ where $a,x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove that $(a-x)^6-3a(a-x)^5+\frac{5}{2} a^2(a-x)^4-\frac{1}{2} a^4 (a-x)^2 <0$ for $0<x<a,$ where $a,x\in\mathbb{R}.$

I'm not sure if what I've done is correct.
Substitute $t=1-\frac{x}{a}.$ Then the polynomial becomes $a^6(t^6-3t^5+\frac{5}{2}t^4-\frac{1}{2}t^2)=a^6t^2(t-1)(t^3-2t^2+\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{1}{2})=a^6t^2(t-1)^2(t^2-t-\frac{1}{2}).$ The quadratic has a positive leading coefficient and roots $\frac{1+ \sqrt{3}}{2}>1$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}<0$ so it is negative on $(0,1)$. Since all other terms are of even degree, they are positive, and so $a^6t^2(t-1)^2(t^2-t-\frac{1}{2})<0.$ $\;{\square}$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Factorizing your given term we obtain $$-\frac{1}{2} x^2 (a-x)^2 \left(a^2+2 a x-2 x^2\right)$$